# Javascript replace with reference to matched group?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string, such as `hello _there_`. I'd like to replace the two underscores with `<div>` and `</div>` respectively, using **JavaScript**. The output would (therefore) look like `hello <div>there</div>`. The string might contain multiple pairs of underscores.

What I am looking for is a way to **either** run a function on each match, the way Ruby does it:

```
"hello _there_".gsub(/_.*?_/) { |m| "<div>" + m[1..-2] + "</div>" }
```

**Or** be able to reference a matched group, again the way it can be done in ruby:

```
"hello _there_".gsub(/_(.*?)_/, "<div>\\1</div>")
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 519, accepted):

```
"hello _there_".replace(/_(.*?)_/, function(a, b){
    return '<div>' + b + '</div>';
})
```

Oh, or you could also:

```
"hello _there_".replace(/_(.*?)_/, "<div>$1</div>")
```

Comment: Does Javascript use `$1` instead of `\1`?  Would someone provide a link to documentation?

Comment: `replacementValue` can be a function and it is passed different arguments based on the catch groups?  Amazing!

Comment: i found \1 worked but $1 did NOT although I am using the RegExp variation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references

Comment: That's in the regex itself. People are talking about the replacestring.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Saying "the regex itself" doesn't identify which one, as someone might be trying to use a regex for the replace.  There must be many people trying to do this: `"hello _there_".replace(/_(.*?)_/, /<div>\1<\/div>/)`.

Comment: Documentation about function replace https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Answer (score 51):

You can use `replace` instead of `gsub`.

```
"hello _there_".replace(/_(.*?)_/g, "<div>\$1</div>")
```

Comment: You can remove the backslash.

Answer (score 27):

For the replacement string and the replacement pattern as specified by `$`. 
here a resume:

[image]

link to doc : [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter)

```
"hello _there_".replace(/_(.*?)_/g, "<div>$1</div>")
```

**Note:**

If you want to have a `$` in the replacement string use `$$`. Same as with vscode snippet system.