# Regex match second dot in number

Tags: javascript, regex, aptana, replace

I'm trying to match the second dot in a number to replace it later with a white space in my 'find and replace' function in Aptana.

I tried a lot of expressions, none of them worked for me.

For example I take the number:

48.454.714 (I want to replace the dot between 454 and 714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(\d{3})\.(\d{3})
```

and replace the first and second capturing group `\1 \2`

as mentioned by FiveO, you might want to match other numbers of digits too. E.g. one to 3 digits: `\d{1,3}` or any number of digits: `\d+`

Comment: maybe replace the {3} with + as there could be more than just 3 digits

Answer (score 0):

Try with following regex:

```
\d+\.\d+(\.)\d+
```

And replace it with white space.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Now I have a follow up question: How do you replace only a group?

Comment: @dj_rmb Read a bit about regex in JavaScript, you'll quickly have your answer ;)

Comment: @sp00m I assume you know the answer to my question, and instead of helping me here you give me that...

Comment: @dj_rmb Because you should learn how to search. Google -> javascript regex replace only a group -> [first link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234712/javascript-replace-with-reference-to-matched-group)