# javascript | find and replace quote using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like below:

```
[quote="username"]This is a comment string[/quote]
```

Pattern 1: **username**
Pattern 2: **This is a comment string**

Is it possible to replace this to get:

```
<div class="myclass">
   <b>username</b>
   <i>This is a comment string</i>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm trying to find the right solution. Thanks.

Comment: See this existing question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234712/javascript-replace-with-reference-to-matched-group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
'[quote="username"]This is a comment string[/quote]'.replace(/\[quote="(.*?)"\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/, function(text, g1, g2, pos, content){console.log('a', g1, g2); return 'd'})
```