# Wrap specific part of string with HTML element

Tags: javascript, string

Let’s say I have a headline (`<h1>`) that says `The 20 Most Useful Users on Stack Exchange`. Is there a way to add a `<span class="numbers"></span>` element only around the `20` with JavaScript?

Comment: Have you tried to do it on your own?

Comment: Of course there is a way! It depends on what this 20 can be. Numbers, worsds etc'

Comment: @AshwinMukhija I wouldn't ask the question if I knew how to do it on my own now would I?

Comment: Mostly a duplicate of [regex - Javascript replace with reference to matched group? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234712/javascript-replace-with-reference-to-matched-group).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to achieve this is:

```
$('h1').each(function (_, el) {
var $this = $(el);
var h1Content = $this.html();
$this.html(h1Content.replace(/(\d+)/, '<span>$1</span>'));
});
```

This assumes you want the first number. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xSh2z/)**

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the string will only have one set of digits:

```
function wrapNum(str) {
    return str.replace(/\d+/, '<span>$&</span>');
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/vgZ55/) | [`.replace()` Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: Otherwise, just add a global flag: `/\d+/g`