# Replace a string with HTML inside a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have

```
<div class="test">hello everyone</div>
```

and I want to change each hello in this div with

```
<h1>helllo</h1>
```

for example I've used

```
$(this).text().replace("hello", "<h1>hello<h1>");
```

but it outputs

```
<h1>hello</h1>
```

I want it apply as HTML not as text how can I do it?

Comment: try using $(this).html() and setting it in the same manner

Comment: tried it didn't work either

Comment: Try to use the class selector?

Comment: `$(this).html($(this).html().replace("hello", "<h1>hello</h1>"));`

Comment: What does `$(this)` refer to in your code? How are you invoking your jQuery?

Comment: `[object Object]` that was the output

Comment: `$(".code").text(function () {
                return $(this).html($(this).html().replace("int", "<span class='var'>int</span>"));
 });`

Comment: @mouhamdAgoumi, that is not what I suggested.

Comment: `$(".code").html($(".code").html().replace("int", "<span class='var'>int</span>"));` ... what you wrote should be this (without any wrapping function).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change tag using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389751/change-tag-using-javascript)

Comment: can't be used for multiple times? for looking more than just one word?

Comment: Or [Wrap specific part of string with HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17498746/215552) or [JavaScript regex - How to wrap matches with tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29616937/215552)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in a pure JavaScript approach, you can use the [innerHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property to replace your string with html like this:

```js
var x = document.querySelector(".test");
x.innerHTML = x.innerHTML.replace("hello", "<h1>hello</h1>");
```

```html
<div class="test">hello everyone</div>
```

Comment: The backticks aren't necessary, you don't need template strings here

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel Thanks for the heads up :) Answer updated mate.

Comment: doesn't work when you are locking for two words to change

Comment: @mouhamdAgoumi It does work for a string with multiple words too. Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/1gy7ukr5/10/) to see how I changed two words from a string.

Comment: I didn't mean "hello world" for example I meant 
`x.innerHTML = x.innerHTML.replace("hello", "<h1>hello</h1>");`
`x.innerHTML = x.innerHTML.replace("world", "<h2>World</h2>");`

Comment: @mouhamdAgoumi The current solution works for that too. Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/1gy7ukr5/14/

Answer (score 1):

Your code is only replacing the text returned. That too it wont replace in the DOM, it will only be in javascript. So after replacing the text, render the returned value using .html()

```js
var $myDiv = $('.test');
$myDiv.html($myDiv.text().replace("hello", "<h1>hello</h1>"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">hello everyone</div>
```

Comment: Answers are better when you provide explanation of the code you suggested.

Comment: This code was simple and self explanatory, hence I did not explain it. Now I have updated

Answer (score 0):

.html() to access & change the html, regex to replace hello with `<h1>hello</h1>`

```
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/hello/g,"<h1>helllo</h1>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I wanted to highlight a code in my div but since I didn't have a lot of time to do that I just used [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) to do that but I'm still looking for a good idea to do that

Answer (score -3):

The code you have written for this replacement is perfectly nice but instead replacing a particular section, you are replacing complete div data

1.) Store div content to a variable e.g. var myDiv

2.) Replace desired content

3.) Put back replaced portion back to music

**Example**

```
jQuery(".test").html(function(){
      jQuery(this).text().replace("hello", "<h1>hello</h1>");
})
```

Comment: text() will html-encode the argument, the html will be `&lt;h1&gt;hello&lt;h1&gt;` - and you forgot to save the results anywhere.. and you don't use a regex to match every hello, just the first will be replaced.