# Regex convert a <div> to <br>

Tags: javascript, regex

**Input:**

```
<div>Many</div><div>Lines</div><div>Goes</div><div>Here</div>
```

**Expected output:**

```
Many<br>Lines<br>Goes<br>Here
```

I tried an approach like this:

```
input = input.replace("<div>", ""),
input = input.replace("</div>", "<br>")
```

And while that works the solution is not optimal.

Cheers

Comment: <br> is not clean, <br /> would be.

Comment: Could you please let me know, what is input? is it any variable or control?

Comment: *"And while that works the solution is not optimal."* No it doesn't. It only replaces the first one.

Comment: Your present example can be easily solved with string manipulations (with regex or not). But if you want to apply this to an HTML document in the real life, the best way is to use the DOM.

Comment: @Robert: There's nothing unclean about `<br>` unless you're using XHTML. The solidus at the end is *tolerated* in HTML on void elements; that's all. It has exactly zero effect.

Comment: Have you not seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1762224) before:?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use global regex, instead of strings :

```
input = input.replace(/<div>/g, '');
input = input.replace(/<\/div>/g, '<br>');

console.log(input); // Many<br>Lines<br>Goes<br>Here<br>
```

### More details :

[replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function can take, as first parameter :

- a String, like `'</div>'`
- a RegExp, like `/<\/div>/`

Whatever you're using a String or a RegExp, `replace()` will find the first match, and replace it. **The first match only.**
You need to specify that the replace is global (ie. every match should be replaced).

You've got two options to make a global replace :

- Use regex flags :
  `input.replace(/<\/div>/g, '<br>');`
- Use the third parameter, which is a comination of flags :
  `input.replace('</div>', '<br>', 'g');`

### Warning :

> The use of the flags parameter in the String.replace method is non-standard. Instead of using this parameter, use a RegExp object with the corresponding flags.

As the third parameter way is **not a standart**, you're encouraged to use RegExp way.

### Just for fun :

You also can do it in a single line :

```
input = input.replace(/<(\/)?div>/g, function(m, p) { return p ? '<br>' : ''; });
/*
input.replace(
    /<(\/)?div>/g,       -> regex to match '<div>' and '</div>'
    function(m, p) {     -> m = whole match, p = first capturing group
        return p         -> if p is defined, ie. if we've got a slash
            ? '<br>'     -> we matched '</div>', return '<br>'
            : '';        -> we matched '<div>', return ''
    }
);
*/
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant `/g`lobal.

Comment: How exactly is that any different performance wise from the two replaces he is already doing?

Comment: @rdrkt Added some details to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
input = replace(/<div>(.*?)<\/div>/, "$1<br>")
```

Several other options to perform replace using matched groups can be found in this [question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1234712/812912).

Comment: In case you have nested `div` elements, this code will destroy the structure and create semantically invalid HTML code like this: `<div><div>Hello</div></div>` results in `Hello<br></div>`

Comment: @fero Looking at OP's question it seemed to me that it is not possible to have nested `<div>`-s. If that is possible however I can not think of a better option then to use the default(greedy) version of `*` multiple times which will generally perform worse than the solution proposed by zessx.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, in both cases. I just wanted to mention that your code won't work with nested `div`s. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try to manipulate the DOM. The script below will produce what you need:

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C84R4/2)</kbd>

```
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(
        newNode,
        referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

var divTags = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i = 0; i < divTags.length;) {
    var div = divTags[i];
    var text = document.createTextNode(div.innerHTML);

    div.parentNode.replaceChild(text, div);
    insertAfter(text, document.createElement('br'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you gave us a better indication of what kind of strings can fall between the `<div>` and `</div>`.

http://regexr.com?37j2q

```
input = input.replace(new RegExp("<div>([a-zA-Z0-9]+)</div>", "mg"), "\$1<br>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2GwQv/2/