# Add span tags to text with a certain character before it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a comment textarea and a preview block (to show it formatted like here on SO).

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="comment"></textarea>
<div id="preview-block">
    <p id="text"></p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('#text').text($('textarea#comment').val());
},10);
```

How would I add `span` tags with a `>` before it to style it?

```
>Here is a quote.

Here is not a quote.
```

So the formatted HTML would be something like:

```
<div id="preview-block">
    <p id="text"><span class="quote">Here is a quote.</span><br> Here is not a quote.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would likely want to use regex to match parts of the string which matches your formatting rules.

See [this regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/tT6qP1/1), which contains a simple regex which matches the exact rule you used as an example.

```
>.+[\r\n]+
```

Which matches the character > then any character except newline 1 or more times. Then it has to end with a newline.

Then you would replace it with the matched content inside a span, see for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234712/javascript-replace-with-reference-to-matched-group).

[Here is a simple working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqte9os8/). Just click the button to see the effect. You might also want to add similar replacements for newline to a 
 tag, etc. Hope this helps!

```
var text = $('#myTextArea').val();

text = text.replace(/>.+[\r\n]+/g, function(a){
    return '<span class="quote">' + a + '</span>';
})
```

Comment: How would I go about doing that in JS? I'm not familiar with regex at all. `">quoted text".replace(/>.+[\r\n]+/g, "?????")`

Comment: For some reason yours wasn't working. But this seems to work: `setInterval(function(){
    var str = $('textarea#comment').val();
    str = str.replace(/>/g, "<span class='quoted-text'>");
    str = str.replace(/[\n\r]/g, "</span><br>");
    $('#text').html(str);
  },10);`

Comment: Edited with a working example based on the links I provided if you want to take a look. Your solution works fine as well.

Answer (score -1):

To set the content for `$('#text')`, use `$('#text').html(<content>)`.

**CSS**

```
span.quote:before {
    content: ">";
}
```

Don't forget to check [browser support](https://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/) for the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements.