# Replace/highlight string in JavaScript - keep the case sensitivity

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to highlight a single string in a sentence. The replacement should work with case insensitive characters (like the string `foo` in the sentence `My Foo bar`).

This is no problem for me:

```
var regEx = new RegExp(this._searchString, "gi");
var label = $(item).text();
label = label.replace(regEx, '<span style="font-weight:bold;">' + this._searchString + '</span>');
$(item).html(label);
```

The problem here is:
If I search and replace `foo` in `My Foo bar`, the result will be
`My <span style="font-weight:bold;">foo</span> bar`, but what I want is `My <span style="font-weight:bold;">Foo</span> bar`.

So the search should ignore case sensitivity, but not the replacement. Any idea how to do it? The only way I see, is to first check if the string contains the searched string, extract it (with the case sensitivity), modify it and put it back into the string. But that seems to be too much work for me, isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to capture your string in a group by wrapping it in parentheses and reference with `$1` it in the replacement string.

**EDIT:** I wrapped the matching pattern with `\b` to match whole words only.

```js
    var original_string = 'My Foo bar',
        variable = 'foo',
        regex = new RegExp('(\\b'+variable+'\\b)', 'gi'); // note the parentheses around variable
    console.log(original_string.replace(regex, 'precious $1 is really')); // here you reference the 1st capture with $1
```

Comment: How to pass a javascript variable inside of the RegEx? I tried `'/(' + variable + ')/gi'`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: That's because you made a regular expression into a string by wrapping it in quotes. Use the `RegExp` constructor. `var reg = RegExp('(' + variable + ')', 'gi');`

Answer (score 1):

Using this method: [Javascript replace with reference to matched group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234712/javascript-replace-with-reference-to-matched-group)

```js
str = $("#test").text()

var regEx = new RegExp("foo", "gi");

str = str.replace(regEx, function(a,b){
    console.log(a)
 return '<span style="font-weight:bold;color:red">' + a + '</span>'
})

$("#test").html(str)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">My Foo bar with Foos and fOO</div>
```