# Javascript get all text in between string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string content that gets delivered to me via TCP. This info is only relevant because it means that I do not consistently retrieve the same string. I have a `<start>` and `<stop>` separator to ensure that any time I get the data via TCP, I am outputting the full content.

My incoming content looks like so:

`<start>Apple Bandana Cadillac<stop>`

I want to get everything in between `<start>` and `<stop>`. So just `Apple Bandana Cadillac`.

My script to do this looks like so:

```
servercsv.on("connection", function(socket){
    let d_basic = "";
    socket.on('data', function(data){
        d_basic += data.toString();
        let d_csvindex = d_basic.indexOf('<stop>');
            while (d_csvindex > -1){
                try {
                    let strang = d_basic.substring(0, d_csvindex);
                    let dyson = strang.replace(/<start>/g, '');
                    let dson = papaparse.parse(dyson);
                    myfunction(dson);
                }
                catch(e){ console.log(e); }
                d_basic = d_basic.substring(d_csvindex+1);
                d_csvindex = d_basic.indexOf('<stop>');
            }
    });
});
```

What this means is that I am getting everything before the `<stop>` string and outputting it. I have also included the line `let dyson = strang.replace(/<start>/g, '');` because I want to remove the `<start>` text.

However, because this is TCP, I am not guranteed to get all parts of this string. As a result, I frequently get back `stop>Apple Bandana Cadillac<stop>` or some variation of this (such as `start>Apple Bandana Cadillac<stop>`. It is not consistent enough that I can just do `strang.replace("start>", "")`

Ideally, I would like my separator to select content that is in between `<start>` and `<stop>`. Not just `<stop>`. However, I am unsure how to do so.

Alternatively, I can also settle for a regex that retrieves all combination of `<start><stop>` strings during my while loop, and just delete them. So check for `<, s, t, a, r, t` individually and so forth. But unsure how to implement regex to delete portions of a whole string.

Comment: uhhh BECAUSE this is TCP, all piece of data sent to the client are in the correct order and nothing should be missed. TCP protocol has a mechanism to ask for missing data (contrary to UDP).

Comment: option1, use string.split('<stop>'). You will get an array of string which already split by "<stop>", then you replace the start tag; option 2, use  regular expression to get what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex with [**`replace()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method:

```
/<st.*?>(.*?)(?!<st)/g
```

**Literal.................................................:** `<st`

**Any char zero or more times [lazily](http://trentrichardson.com/2012/07/13/5-must-know-javascript-regex-tips/)...:** `.*?`

**Literal..................................................:** `>`

**Begin [capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1234725/2813224)..........................:** `(`

**Any char zero or more times [lazily](http://trentrichardson.com/2012/07/13/5-must-know-javascript-regex-tips/)...:** `.*?`

**End [capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1234725/2813224).............................:** `)`

**Begin [negative lookahead](http://trentrichardson.com/2012/07/13/5-must-know-javascript-regex-tips/).................:** `(?!`

**Literal...................................................:** `<st`

**End [negative lookahead](http://trentrichardson.com/2012/07/13/5-must-know-javascript-regex-tips/)....................:** `)`

In the Demo below notice that the test example consists of multiple lines, and variances of `<start>` and `<stop>` (basically `<st`).

---

#### Demo 1

```js
var rgx = /<st.*?>(.*?)(?!<st)/g;

var str = `<start>Apple Bandana Cadillac<stop>
<stop>Grapes Trampoline Ham<stop>
<start>Kebab Matador Pencil<start>`;

var res = str.replace(rgx, `$1`);

console.log(res);
```

---

#### Update

> *"say I have `op>`Grapes Trampoline Ham`<stop>`...still trying to remove all parts of the string `<stop>`"*

```
/^(.*?>)(.*?)(<.*?)$/gm;
```

A simple explanation will have to do since a step-by-step such as Demo 1 would take too much time.

- This RegEx is multiline. `/m`
- `^`..........Begin line.
- `(.*?>)`..Lazily capture everything until literal `>`........[Return as `$1`]
- `(.*?)`...Then lazily capture everything until................[Return as `$2`]
- `(<.*?)`..Literal `<` and lazily capture everything until..[Return as `$3`]
- `$`...........End line.

The trick is to replace the second capture `$2` and leave `$1` and `$3` alone.

#### Demo 2

```js
var rgx = /^(.*?>)(.*?)(<.*?)$/gm;

var str = `<start>Apple Bandana Cadillac<stop>
<stop>Grapes Trampoline Ham<stop>
<start>Kebab Matador Pencil<start>
op>Score False Razor<stop>
`;

var res = str.replace(rgx, `$2`);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: the only issue i have with this is, say I have `op>Grapes Trampoline Ham<stop>` my output will be `op>Grapes Trampoline Ham`. still trying to remove all parts of the string `<stop>`

Comment: See update, this will work as long as your input is multiline.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you get full response:

```
var test = "<start>Apple Bandana Cadillac<stop>";
var testRE = test.match("<start>(.*)<stop>"); 
testRE[1] //"Apple Bandana Cadillac"
```

If there are new lines between `<start>` and `<stop>`

```
var test = "<start>Apple Bandana Cadillac<stop>";
var testRE = test.match("<start>([\\S\\s]*)<stop>"); 
testRE[1] //"Apple Bandana Cadillac"
```

Using regular expressions capturing group here.

Comment: just a note in case: this will not work if there are new lines between `<start>` and `<stop>`. To capture multiline content he can use `[\s\S]*` instead of `.*`