# JavaScript: Wrap all text between apostrophes in a span

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small piece of text:
`"some text" some more text "even more text"`

What I wanna do is to wrap everything between apostrophes in a span container just like hilight.js does. I can't really find a way to make it working.

Could somebody please explain me what would be the ideal way to do this?

```js
var body = document.querySelector('body');

var code = body.innerHTML;
var code = code.replace(/"(.*?)"/g,"<span>---</span>");
body.innerHTML = code;
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
<p>Corrent result:</p>
"some text" some more text "even more text"
<p>The result would be:</p>
<p><span>some text</span> some more text <span>even more text</span></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Replace `---` with `$1`.

Comment: Can you explain me how does it work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234712/javascript-replace-with-reference-to-matched-group

Comment: I'm not sure if I would want to do that... The browser would recognize `$1` as a variable

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Also, make sure you’re doing that on something that’s originally HTML, though, and that doesn’t have attributes. It’s easy to make a script injection vulnerability or mangle real-world HTML. So: are you doing this on HTML, or on text?

Comment: So I would just need to replace the content of the string itself?

Comment: @Rt- It's HTML stored in a variable, after wrapping the text I write it back onto the page.

Comment: And it never has any attributes in it, like `<a href="…">`?

Comment: The only attribute I use is the class attribute so I can style the wrapper element.

Comment: Great, just wanted to make sure it was safe to use :D

Answer (score 1):

You're quite close. You can use `$n` syntax in your replace string which will correspond to the `n`'th capture group.

```js
let x = '"yo" bro "more"';
let y = x.replace(/"(.*?)"/g, '<span>$1</span>');
console.log(y);
```

[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter)