# Replacing substring in a numeric pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string

```
text *inner text 1* text2 *inner text 2*
```

I have to replace the substrings with `<span></span>`

Output

```
text <span>inner text 1</span> text2 <span>inner text 2</span>
```

I tried this

```
replace(/[*]/g,"<span>")
```

I know using /g is going to replace all the occurrences with `<span>` also I cannot put two params in replace so the question is how to replace **every even occurrences** with `</span>`

Comment: Have you tried catching the "space*" and "*space" separately with their own regular expressions?

Comment: The trick is to use backreferences in capturing groups of your regular expressions.
https://javascript.info/regexp-backreferences has an example using quotation marks. Let me try to come up with an answer matching your use case.

Comment: @Ryuno-Ki - A regular expression could be a good answer here, but I don't think you need backreferences for this...?

Answer (score 2):

Regex

```
\*([^\*]+)\*
```

```js
let str = 'text *inner text 1* text2 *inner text 2*'

console.log(str.replace(/\*([^\*]+)\*/g, '<span>$1</span>'))
```

**Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/wj9WkA/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a counter and the remainder operator, giving a callback to `replace`:

```
let counter = 0;
result = original.replace(/[*]/g, () => ++counter % 2 ? "<span>" : "</span>");
```

Live Example:

```js
const original = "text *inner text 1* text2 *inner text 2*";
let counter = 0;
const result = original.replace(/[*]/g, () => ++counter % 2 ? "<span>" : "</span>");
console.log(result);
```

That works because `1 % 2` is `1` which is truthy, but `2 % 2` is `0` which is falsy, and `3 % 2` is `1` which is truthy...

Another approach would be to use a regular expression to search for matches between two `*`, using a capture group to capture the matches:

```
result = original.replace(/\*(.*?)\*/g, "<span>$1</span>");
```

Live Example:

```js
const original = "text *inner text 1* text2 *inner text 2*";
let counter = 0;
const result = original.replace(/\*(.*?)\*/g, "<span>$1</span>");
console.log(result);
```

---

That's assuming it's really okay to work purely on the basis of alternating `*` characters.

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
str.replace(/([*])([\w ]+)\1/g, '<span>$2</span>');
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `([*])` Match `*` and capture in group #1
- `([\w ]+)` Match 1+ word or space character and capture in group #2
- `\1` is used to make string ends with same `*` as in group #1
- Replacement is `<span>$2</span>` to wrap string in group #2 in `<span>` and `</span>`

**Demo:**

```js
const str = 'text *inner text 1* text2 *inner text 2*';

const res = str.replace(/([*])([\w ]+)\1/g, '<span>$2</span>');

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/1234725/5189920:

```js
var string = 'text *inner text 1* text1 *inner text 2* text2';
var newString = string.replace(/\*([\w\s]+[^*])\*/g, '<span>$1</span>');
console.log(newString);
```

Explanation: The regular expression is searching for a literal asterisk (`\*`), followed by a capturing group (`(...)`). This group can be referenced back by `$1` in the second argument. In it, we are capturing all word (`\w`) and whitespace (`\s`) up until the next asterisk (`[^*]`). The search applies globally (`/g`).

The second argument is referenced the captured group and replaced the parts around it (`\*`).